# phpMyAdmin database: ID #s are all zero

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I have a database table in phpMyAdmin that has:
[id, username, password, email, firstname, lastname, lastlogin]
Works just fine.  The problem is it doesn't give each user an id number (they are all zeros and I want 1,2,3...). Every time a user submits their information from a form to the database, they should be assigned a number. First person to submit should be ID 1, second should be ID 2, and so on. How can I fix this in phpMyAdmin?
Thank you.

Comment: The `id` field is set to `AUTO_INCREMENT`???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AUTO_INCREMENT should work just fine to solve your problem. Dagon posted a solution on how to alter your table which should work perfectly. If you prefer to create the table again but with AUTO_INCREMENT in place, you can use the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  username ..., 
  password ...,
  email ..., 
  firstname ..., 
  lastname ..., 
  lastlogin ...,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
// '...' represents the datatypes and other characteristics of the
// specific columns/fields
```

Let me know if that worked for you!

Comment: Thanks everybody...going to try and fix this right now!....I tried auto increment, but I got an error (#1075 incorrect table definition, there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as key) I'm prob just going to redo the table again and see what happens.

Comment: @HLD alright, let me know if redoing the table as shown above worked

Comment: @HLD Cool! Please accept (green checkmark) the answer that you believe best answers your question so that future users can know when reading through this page.

Answer (score 1):

In phpMyAdmin, select your table and go to the "Structure" tab. Then on the row for your ID field, check the box under "A_I" to turn on auto increment.

To force all your records to update so they have different ID numbers, delete the ID column and then add it back again with the incrementing enabled.

Make sure that under "Index" you select "PRIMARY KEY", or else it will throw an error.

Comment: just dont do this if your using  foreign keys

Comment: @dagon Well the keys are all 0 right now, so the foreign keys are broken anyway.

Comment: yes but unless you run `DROP FOREIGN KEY` first you may generate some *interesting* error messages

Comment: I've updated my answer. Make sure you set the ID to be the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

to add auto increment if required:

```
 ALTER TABLE `YOUR_TABLE` CHANGE `id` `id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

to fix the existing lack of id's

```
SET @count = 0;
UPDATE `YOUR_TABLE` SET `YOUR_TABLE`.`id` = @count:= @count + 1;
```

then

```
ALTER TABLE `YOUR_TABLE` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```